# Vimeo Rails Devise OmniAuth SSL Error Windows Only

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ssl, devise

I have a vimeo sign-in on my rails App which works fine when the app runs on a mac however on my windows system (and any windows 10 machine in general that I have) I get this error:

```
Faraday::SSLError at /users/auth/vimeo/callback
SSL_connect returned=1 errno=0 state=SSLv3 read server certificate B: certificate verify failed
```

Everywhere I have read about the error says that I have to help the app locate the certificates - I have not had any success with this and am not sure what I should be doing to fix things.

My understanding is that a folder that contains certificates is the path and in the config/initializers/devise.rb you need to type this in

i.e.
  config.omniauth :vimeo, 'key', 'key' "!SOME PATH HERE!"

I'm using rails FTW and I've tried many different methods to try and get this to work with no success. Help appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You've a few options here.

#### Option #1

You can to tell Faraday, which the omniauth adapter is using, to manually set the certificate you want to use.

You need to dig into the adapter code to do this.

```
connection = Faraday.new 'https://example.com', :ssl => {
    :client_cert  => ...,
    :client_key   => ...,
    :ca_file      => ...,
    :ca_path      => ...,
    :cert_store   => ...
  }
```

#### Option #2

Add the certificate that's missing to the computer/server you're using. How this is done depends on you OS.

#### Option #3

**A quick, but unsafe solution**

Turn off SSL verification **globally**.

```
OpenSSL::SSL::VERIFY_PEER = OpenSSL::SSL::VERIFY_NONE
```

Comment: I am guessing windows is missing the certificate so I in turn move to option 2 and try and get one to put in the location where they should be kept?? And where do I get one where the Mac system seems to have a valid one?